# Database indices for log table

Tags: mysql, database, logging, indexing, entity-attribute-value

I need to create log table in a database. Each log will have various parameters. This is the table design I've come up.

```
 Table Log
============
ID(INT)
Action(INT)
Created(TIMESTAMP)

 Table Parameter
================
ID(INT)
ActionID(INT)
Title(VARCHAR(50))
VALUE(VARCHAR(300))
```

My question is, I need to perform complex queries on this log table such as

> - Who made what action and when?
>   Who means I need to check parameters if title = "personID" and what means I need to check action code.
> - Total of prices of sale actions
>   For this one, I need to check the action code for "sale" (say 3 (as integer)) and then I need to retrieve parameters of that actions with title "price" and then cast them to double and sum them up.

This queries will expand and I need to ensure that my design can answer more complex queries. I know that indices give great boosts but I am not very sure where I need to add to get the most out of database engine. The underlying database is MySQL.

Which fields should I have indices? Or is my design accurate for my purpose? I am also using InnoDB engine.

### Edit

Sample SQL

```
SELECT LOG.ID, LOG.ACTION, LOG.CREATED FROM LOG, PARAMETER
    WHERE PARAMETER.ACTIONID = ACTION.ID AND 
          PARAMETER.TITLE = "PERSONNAME" AND 
          PARAMETER.VALUE = 'JOHN' AND 
          PARAMETER.TITLE = "PRICE" AND 
          (CAST(PARAMETER.VALUE AS DOUBLE) > 30.0) AND 
          PARAMETER.TITLE = "DATE" AND 
          (CAST(PARAMETER.VALUE AS TIMESTAMP) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
```

The more conditions we have, the more `Parameter.TITLE` and `Parameter.VALUE` pairs will be used in the SQL.

Comment: Can't decide on the indexes until we see the `SELECT`.

Comment: @RickJames I've edited the question with a possible query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` to `PARAMETER` multiple times, once per key-value pair that you are testing for.  There are many examples; follow the Entity-Attribute-Value tag I added.

Since this is an EAV problem, you will have troubles with performance.

One improvement can be found in the changes I advocate for WP [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta)

Another discussion is [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) on why not to hide the things you want to filter on in the K-V table.  And an alternative.